# How to remove + from string except at beginning using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I’m looking to remove + from a string except at the initial position using javascript replace and regex.

Input: +123+45+
Expected result: +12345

Please help

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is nothing to debug here. Take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const string = '+123+45+'
console.log(string.replace(/([^^])\+/g, '$1'))
```

https://regexr.com/61g3c

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below regex java script. Replace all plus sign except first occurrence.

```js
const givenString = '+123+45+'
let index = 0

let result = givenString.replace(/\+/g, (item) => (!index++ ? item : ""));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
input = '+123+45+';
regex = new RegExp('(?!^)(\\+)', 'g');

output = input.replace(regex, '');

console.log(output);
```